# Add a web User to SQL without using ASP.NET Configuration button in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server

Hello how can I add users and give them roles without using the ASP.NET Configuration button in Visual Studio

I wrote a web site that requires a login.

I am not using SQL express to hold user information
I ran aspnet_regsql and configured some users using the ASP.NET Configuration button.
I uploaded the database to the server and no I need to add a user.

By boss is in a meeting with the client at this very moment so this is failry urgent.

I hope an pray that I have explained what I want well enough to get some help.

There must be a way of going to the server database and adding a user.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is all in the Membership Provider and can be controlled programatically. The best place to start is look at a complete overview, as it will help you better understand how to do this. As an example: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Do not try to do this using SQL Queries alone, unless you have configured the membership provider to use no encryption. If you try to circumvent, which is possible in some instances, you will mess things up. In the standard Membership Provider, you have methods to create users and put them in roles. It is a bit kludgy and I have personally customized a bit to make things easier, but the standard classes are not that unwieldy with creation of users and putting them in roles (big issue was changing without a customized membership provider).

Comment: Oh dear, I don't have time to read the 4guys thing. Sadly, I think what you are saying is that the only way I can add a user is by including a maintenance section in the website itself. Again I certainly don't have time for that either. Thanks anyway Gregory :-(

Answer (score 0):

First in master database:

```
use master
go
create login [loginname] from windows
```

--- OR
--- create login [loginname] with password='passw0rrrd' 
    go

Then in your database

```
use your_database
go
create user [username] from login [loginname]
go
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'username'
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'username'
grant execute to [username]
go
```

This should sort you out.
In long term it is better to create a database role with required permissions. The only thing you have to do then is to add user to this role.

Regards

Piotr

Comment: Hello @Piotr, Many thanks for your answer.
The meeting is over now and the client was not best pleased.
However I still need to know how do do this.
Perhaps I should have mentioned that I know NOTHING about sql server apart from how to create a database. I am an administrator so I can probably do everything you suggested but can't get past the create login bit because I have now idea what to enter instead of login name.
Whatever I enter I get an erro message something like
'slobbo' is not a valid Windows NT name. Give the complete name: <domain\username>.

Comment: Hello @Piotr continued... I don't suppose you can tell me what I should enter here considering I don't know what what the domain is or even what my username is.
'sa' did not work !
I fully expect you to give up on me as beyond help but I can always hope.
Many thanks anyway.

Comment: well if you have server in the domain and the user also belongs to the domain, the login name would be [domain\username]. you have to ask him about the username he uses to log on to domain. 
If you want to use SQL Server authentication, you have to use the second form 

create login [loginname] with password = 'strongpassword'

Then user has to use this name and password to connect to the database.

Comment: Oh dear, I am starting to wonder if I may not have explained things clearly in my initial post ( I was in a hurry)
I have a web site. People login in to that website using user names and passwords that I gave them using the configuration button in visual studio.
I need to add more users to the database tables so they can also access the website.
In this scenario, these potential users obviously don't log into the database directly so obviusly don;t have usernames. 
It seems I have wasted your time - sorry Piotr.

Comment: ah no worries. it looks like I didn't read carefully enough :)